# How to make your Onchange event on a combo box to fetch data from a model in ruby?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code for

**Model**

```
class Tender < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :title, :buyer_name, :category, :opening_date, :closing_date, :bid_amount, :description, :status

end
```

**Controller**(index action)

```
class TendersController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :signed_in_user


  def index
    if signed_in?
         @tenders= Tender.where("company_id= ? ", current_user.company.id )  

    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.js
      format.json { render json: @tenders }

    end
  end
```

**View** (index page)

```
<div class="span6 offset3" >  


        Filter by status &nbsp;

        <%= form_tag tenders_path, :remote => true, :method=>'post' do %>
            <%= select_tag("status", options_for_select([['Open', 'Opem'],
                ['Closed', 'Closed'],['Won','Won']])) %>

        <% end %>                       

        <div id="flash"> </div>    

    </div>

</div>


<table border="1" id="tender_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Bid amount</th>
   </tr> 

<% @tenders.each do |tender| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= tender.title %></td>
    <td><%= tender.status %></td>    
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

I also have `tenders.js.coffee` and `index.js.erb`

I am using  rails 3.2.2 and ruby 1.9

What I want to do is, let the user select a **status** from the combo box. Then using an onchange event I want to send the selected value to a controller action (I think it should be index action but correct me if I am wrong). Based on the selcted status, I want fetch list of tenders from the db and send those lists to the view so that it will display(replace the current table ) it on the index page. So far I am trying to use Ajax. Any help would appreciated. I spend more than 4 days on this and couldnt figure out what to do.

The original question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279655/how-can-i-call-a-controller-action-based-on-combo-box) in case if you want more explanation. By the way I couldnt also figure out the onchange event to work using jquery, javascript or even prototype in `tenders.js.coffee` and `index.js.erb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking that AJAX is not the only solution to your problem. Maybe you can just mark your Tenders in the DOM and then hide and show them with javascript directly. Consider this:

```
#tenders/index.html.erb
#...
<% @tenders.each do |tender| %>
  <tr class="<%= tender.status %>">    <!-- Now we know which ones are closed -->
    <td><%= tender.title %></td>
    <td><%= tender.status %></td>    
  </tr>
<% end %>
#...

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#my_select_box_id').change(function(){
    var class = $(this).val();
    $('tr.' + class).show();
    $('tr[class!=' + class + ']').hide();
  });
});
```

Should be much faster too because there is no backend request involved. And it makes more sense to me because the template already has all the information it needs at render time so there is no need to bother the backend with another request. Good luck.

Comment: I will try both solutions you provided me. Where should I put the jquery in this case? Is it in the file search_by_status.js.erb or in the index.html.erb? I will get back to you if there are any questions.Thanks

Comment: Put it in the index file where your tenders are rendered.

Comment: God bless you my friend. This one worked like a charm. I will try the next one.

Comment: By the way don't you think this will be a problem when there are thousands of tenders. i.e we are querying 1000 tenders but we are not showing them. Would that be a big deal when it comes to memory?

Comment: I think thousands could still be okay. The best way to know is to try it. You can set up a testing database and create 1000 test tenders, then try it with this db. But I think in that case, you should consider pagination(I doubt anyone is going to read through 1000 tenders). That would decrease the number of records per page and thus the number of records your js will work with.

Comment: I also have other tables with pagination and of course I will do pagination for this one as well. But, is there a tweak I should make so that this code you gave me will also work on the pagination?

Comment: It will work right away if you keep to the DOM. From the point of this example you don't care at all whether your records are paginated or not. You just get a bunch of records and then you filter them. That would be in the case above - backend pagination(you request only those records that you need). You can also use frontend pagination(get all records and just hide and show them in batches). But that would be more complicated to manage all the stuff in javascript. It would probably be better to use some kind of framework like ember.js or more lightweight angular.js.

Comment: Or would you like the number of tenders to autocomplete? I mean If I have 20 records per page and I select only the closed ones, then 10 tenders disappear, then you want to display 10 more closed tenders?

Comment: If some one selects, lets say closed tenders, we should display all the closed tenders and paginate them if they are more than 20. So the latter case you mentioned might not suite my need.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you will need AJAX for this. Because with this example you get a batch of tenders using pagination, render the view with this batch and then you can filter but only on this batch. If I understand correctly you wanted to filter first and paginate later. Then it would be better to let the backend do it. And you just telling it 'hey give me 20 closed tenders'.

Comment: BTW. In case if you have any idea I was also wondering how to do this in ruby ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487130/how-to-order-a-table-by-aggregate-function-in-a-ruby

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to do but you have to do small things on quite many places. Ajax is the right choice I think. As you said, first you need a controller action that will serve the AJAX request. This could be your index action, but to me it looks more like a search action.

```
class TendersController < ApplicationController
  # You can extend this later if you need to search by other options
  # Just coding for today ;-)
  def search_by_status
    @tenders = Tender.find_all_by_status params[:status]

    #I think this does not even have to be here
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Then you should create a template tenders/search_by_status.js.erb (it could even be search_by_status.html.erb, but I like to make it evident that this template is used by AJAX) and put your markup there.

Then with jQuery(I don't use CoffeeScript much) you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#my_select_box_id').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'tenders/search_by_status?status=' + $(this).val() //or your custom address
      success: function(serverResponse){
        $('#my_target_element_id').html(serverResponse);      //update the DOM
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Or you can encapsulate this behaviour in a javascript pseudo-class and only call PseduoClass.init() in $(document).ready but this is the easy solution and you can tweak later.

I'm making this on the fly, so some things might not 100% accurate, but generally it's what should work. Let me know if there are any problems ;-).

Comment: I used the previous solution for status case but now I am trying to order the Tender by bid_amount which is displayed in the table together with status and title .. so for that case I used the ajax function but seems like even the jQuery is not executed .. I tried to put alert in ...js.erb file but it is not executed .. here is the link to sample code http://pastie.org/4259361 ... I really appreciate your help. I am new to ruby learning it by building a real project on windows and its a hassle so far!!

Comment: I'm a little confused about that. Do you perhaps have it on github? Would be much easier to view and comment the code there.

Comment: Hey, sorry I did not respond. T'was a busy week. How goes it with your app? In the repo I do not see the template for TendersController#order_by_bid_amount_ajax. Any success?

Comment: Oh yeah, the ajax javascript needs to be placed in the index template. That's from where the AJAX request will be made.

Comment: I made some changes and for now I am using just a button to send the request w/o ajax. It works that way, but I wanted to learn how it works with ajax so that I wont display the whole content every time. I couldn't figure out how to solve that problem and since I don't want to stuck there the way I implemented it is not using ajax so that is why you couldn't see that template

Comment: Ok. If you hit anything, feel free to ask.