# How to order a table by aggregate function in a ruby?

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, aggregate-functions

I have 2 attributes `opening_date` and `closing_date` in a Tender model. On the index page what I display is the remaining date which is (`closing_date-Date.today`). However, remaining date is not saved in a database but I wanted to order and display the data in the table by remaining date. What should I use? Is there an aggregate function for that?

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.2.2

//TendersController

```
 def index
 @tenders= Tender.where("company_id= ? ", current_user.company.id).order('closing_date') 
/* Here I am querying the tender by closing_date but I dont want to do that. What I wanted is I just want to order by (closing_date-Date.today) which is not in the database but should be done on the fly. i.e the smallest the number it should be at the top of the table (index.html.erb) to notify the user the closing date is sooner than they think
*/
end
```

//Tender Model

```
attr_accessible :title, :buyer_name, :category, :opening_date, :closing_date, :bid_amount, :description, :status
```

//index.htm.erb

```
<table border="1" id="tender_table" >
  <tr class="table_header">
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Buyer Name</th>
    <th>Remaining dates</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Bid amount</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

  <% @tenders.each do |tender| %>
<% day_diff= tender.closing_date.to_date-Date.today %>
<tr class=<%= tender.status %>> 
<td><%= tender.title %></td>
    <td><%= tender.buyer_name %></td>
    <td >

        <%  if day_diff < 0 %>
        <FONT COLOR="black"><%= -(day_diff).to_i %> days passed</td>

        <% else if day_diff > 10%>
            <FONT COLOR="green"><%= distance_of_time_in_words(tender.closing_date,Date.today) %></td>                   

        <% end %>
        <% end %>

        <% if day_diff <= 10 and day_diff>=0 %>
                <FONT COLOR="red"><%=distance_of_time_in_words(tender.closing_date,Date.today)+' ' %>left</td>

        <% end %>





    <td><%= tender.status %></td>
    <td><%= tender.bid_amount %></td>


    <%#  tender.description %>

    <td><%= link_to 'Show', tender %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_tender_path(tender) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', tender, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show some code and the queries used. By providing more information we can give better answers.

Comment: How does it look now? I hope I will get a better answer.

Comment: Someone choose to close this question? SMH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sort_by`, but that's on the ruby side and therefore slow on large datasets (the database should handle that). Use `closing_date > NOW()` and an `:order_by`.

Comment: I still want to display those dates < NOW() .. but I display them ass passed (for e.g 10 days passed). But using closing_date > NOW() will omit days where their closing_date already passed. By the way, if I use pagination which has table headers, will be able to order them by the remaining dates when I click the remaining date header?